# AT&T to Intel assembly converter

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm looking for a converter from AT&T-style x86 assembly to Intel-style assembly.

The [Att2Intl](http://www.bumba.net/~hmaon/a2i/) is a DOS executable, and won't run on 64-bit Windows.

The [Gas2masm](http://code.google.com/p/glesquake/source/browse/quake/src/WinQuake/gas2masm/?r=d697515d0dda9bb650a543b80e6cde95cf49e471) is sorely incomplete - it chokes on comments, on `.ascii`, on numerous legitimate commands like `leave` or `movs`, clobbers some identifiers...

Any others out there? The target assembler has to be a Microsoft one, there's no way to switch syntax.

EDIT: about 400,000 lines. Not a one time deal, need a not too often but repeatable process. But I won't have to debug it. :)

Comment: _"won't run on 64-bit Windows"_. [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1)?

Comment: @Michael +1 - if it's one-time job, so why not?

Comment: Att2Intl comes with C source code. Can you recompile it and run it?

Comment: How much code do you have to deal with? Can you just assemble the files and then disassemble them into a different form?  It would take some fixing up of labels and things, but it won't be that bad unless you have huge amounts of code to translate.

Comment: Somebody (hint, hint) ought to write a web page where you can paste in one style and get the other one out.

Comment: @Carl: sounds viable, in fact...

Comment: AT&T to Intel conversion should be quite easy using Perl or Vim regex. I have converted 32-bit x86 code to x86-64 code using Vim regex and it's quite doable. I see no reason why AT&T to Intel would be any more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

There's a not-quite-complete Perl script here that might help you out if you're up for making some modifications/extensions to anything missing: http://boinc.berkeley.edu/android-boinc/libssl/crypto/perlasm/x86_64-xlate.pl

If not, just run Att2Intl in DOSBox or a WinXP VM. If you don't have access to XP, you could also try installing ReactOS in a VM. I believe they used DOSBox source to implement the DOS layer so that may provide a long-term solution without having to resort to actually running DOSBox every time.

Comment: I downloaded the source for Att2Intl. With minimal effort you can make it compile on Linux. It does a decent job, but (1) it doesn't understand the `q` suffix and (2) it loses indentation. The former of which presumably is a bug. The perl script linked can be found [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/perlasm/x86_64-xlate.pl) and does a decent job. You can invoke it with `cat att.s | ./x64_64-xlate.pl nasm`.

Comment: Is there any progress on such tools?

Comment: Link in answer is dead but I suspect this is the same file that it was pointing to https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/perlasm/x86_64-xlate.pl